# React Navigation: Tab screen without corresponding bottom tab icon?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native app where the client wants to have a tab without a corresponding icon in the toolbar (it will be navigated to via `navigation.navigate('example')`, so that when this tab is active, the other tab icons are not (as would be achieved by nesting a navigator within).

Something like this results in a blank space where the icon would be but does not remove it:

```
<Tab.Screen
  name="Example"
  component={Example}
  options={{
    tabBarIcon: false
  }}
/>
```

And you end up with something like this:

[image: tab bar example]

Comment: Cant you nest the screen into a different navigator, as you are anyway using navigation.navigate?

Comment: I agree that is the way to go, but the client does not want the parent tab icon to be `active` in that case - so I suppose the question could also be about overriding the `activeTintColor` in that case.